# Azure Data Factory - convert Json Array to Json Object

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I retrieve data using Azure Data Factory from an OnPremise database and the output I get is as follows:

```
{
  "value":[
    {
     "JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-XXXXXXX":"{\"productUsages\":[{\"customerId\":3552,\"productId\":120,\"productionDate\":\"2015-02-10\",\"quantity\":1,\"userName\":\"XXXXXXXX\",\"productUsageId\":XXXXXX},{\"customerId\":5098,\"productId\":120,\"productionDate\":\"2015-04-07\",\"quantity\":1,\"userName\":\"ZZZZZZZ\",\"productUsageId\":ZZZZZZ}]}"
  }
 ]
}
```

The entire value array is being serialized into a JSON and I end up with:

```
[{
"productUsages":
[
    {
        "customerId": 3552,
        "productId": 120,
        "productionDate": "2015-02-10",
        "quantity": 1,
        "userName": "XXXXXXXX",
        "productUsageId": XXXXXX
    },
    {
        "customerId": 5098,
        "productId": 120,
        "productionDate": "2015-04-07",
        "quantity": 1,
        "userName": "ZZZZZZZ",
        "productUsageId": ZZZZZZZ
    }
]
}]
```

I need to have a Json Object at a root level, not Json Array ([] replaced with {}). What's the easiest way to achieve that in Azure Data Factory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ADF When you read any Json file it will read as array of Objects by default :

**Sample data While reading Json data:**

[image]

Data preview:

[image]

But when you want to move data to sink in Json format you have option called **Set of objects** you need to select that:

[image]

**Sample data While storing in sink in form of Json data:**

[image]

**Output**

[image]